# Handle flutter routing with unusual flow

Tags: flutter, navigator, stack-navigator

I have situation were I need some guide on navigator,

I have total six screens in my app as shown in graph below.

User can navigate from screen B to screen F via screen E as well as from screen B user can navigate to screen D via screen C.

Now, In one specific condition I need to navigate my user from screen F to screen D in a condition that if user navigates back, app redirects to screen C.

What is the best way to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: see how [Router API](https://medium.com/flutter/learning-flutters-new-navigation-and-routing-system-7c9068155ade) works

Comment: Hey @pskink thanks, It would be great it you can share any code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

try use this https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushReplacement.html . if you in d and navigate to f, use pushReplacement to remove d page.

Comment: But I also need, when user goes to D page from F, and from D page, on backpress user should be navigated to C page. In your case it will not work as if I pushReplace the F to navigate to D, on back press user will be navigates to E not C.